# How do I test my iOS9 app on an ios10 beta device?

Tags: ios, ios9, beta, ios10, xcode8

I don't want to compile for iOS10 yet, but I want to test my iOS9 app on a device running iOS10 beta

Ive installed the Xcode8 beta and upgraded my device to iOS10 beta.

Using Xcode7 Im not able to build to my iOS10 device, I get the error: "Could not find Developer Disk Image"

And using Xcode8 beta I cant compile for iOS9. Ive tried copying the iOS9.3 sdk and simulator from Xcode7 but I still done have the option to select iOS9 as the base sdk.

Anyone know how I can test my iOS9 app on an ios10 beta device?

Comment: The base SDK in Xcode 8 should be set to iOS10. To deploy to iOS 9 or below, you would set the deployment target to the minimum iOS version. What's it currently set to?

Comment: The deployment target just the minimum supported version. I want to compile for iOS9 which means I need to change the base SDK to iOS9

Comment: Ah, as far as I have found, I still need to use Xcode 7 for compiling with iOS 9 as the base SDK.

Comment: I found a solution to my question at this duplicate question (which was poorly named)